# How scroll table and fix head in top

Tags: scroll, css-tables

I create table and fix head and body but I can't scroll it with this CSS:

```
        .t1 tbody {
            height: 100px;
            overflow: auto;
        }

        .t1 thead > tr, tbody {
            display: block;
        }
```

so I find this link : 
http://jsbin.com/bipusabici/edit?html,output
it's work great but my problem is that structure of table is different of normal table with thead and tbody.

This is my fiddle and I want scroll it with this normal table structure:
 http://jsfiddle.net/snicee/46jzhs94/3/

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it by using table with auto widths in css but you can do using fixed width coulmns in css

Comment: please add your code in my fiddle and show me how i fix it .thanks